# Tweepy restricting a search to a single user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to search through a users own tweets using the tweepy api, and return the tweets that contain whatever keywords the user enters. So if the user enters "Blue" as a keyword, it will search through all of that users tweets, and return any tweets containing the string "Blue".

Here's my code so far, it runs, but it seems to run infinitely all sorts of random tweets. How do I restrict the search to a single user?

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="Blue", rpp=100, show_user=True).items():
    print status.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the user's twitter handle using `from:user` in the query:

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="Blue from:blueperson", rpp=100, show_user=True).items():
    print status.text
```

Comment: Can I use multiple username in it ?